# runnig c# edited test from selenium with Nunit - and getting reports

Tags: selenium, nunit, gallio

I used selenium RC to create some tests, edited with c# and succeeded in running the tests using Nunit.

Now - I would like to get an informative report showing the the test run results.
I can i get a report?
I tried the console option report of Nunit - but couldnt get it to run my assembly. 
Then I looked at Gallio Icarus - but couldn't get it to load my assembly.

Any ideas of how can i get a report?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) produces a nice report, and it runs tests written for NUnit, under Visual Studio.